# How to disable Javers Mongo Starter

Tags: javers

We are currently introducing Javers into our spring applications for auditing. We have our entities and other central classes defined in a single project that some of our APIs use as a dependency. I noticed there are properties to disable SQL management for various purposes but not for mongo. We have some APIs that will be sending up audit data and others that will not.

Is there a property or configuration that can disable the attempt to connect to the mongo/document DB and the creation of the DBs and collections for the mongo starter?

Comment: Looking at the source for Javers this could be implemented on this class https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo/src/main/java/org/javers/spring/boot/mongo/JaversMongoAutoConfiguration.java, adding a "ConditionalOnProperty" annotation on the configuration class

Comment: you can always use InMemoryRepository when you don't want to persist snapshots